# Find target architecture for Linux system using command line

Tags: linux

I am working with a proprietary unit used for industrial applications that has it's own development process. This unit runs a version of Linux but is shipped without a C++ compiler. I am attempting to create a compiler for this unit from source code using a different Ubuntu 18.04 system. I am following this guide: https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/

I need to know how to find the target architecture for the following command:
    `../binutils-2.24/configure --prefix=/opt/cross --target=aarch64-linux --disable-multilib`

The example in the guide is `aarch64-linux` but I'm not sure how to figure out what I need to use for the particular unit I'm creating the compiler for. I have access to the command line on the unit although some commands may be missing.

What is the target and how do I figure out what my unit is using?

Comment: Does the `arch` command do what you want?

Comment: Also see [Configuration Names](https://www.airs.com/ian/configure/configure_4.html) and [Cross Compilation Tools](https://www.airs.com/ian/configure/configure_5.html#SEC30) in the Autotools manual.

Answer (score 0):

would uname contain the info you need ?

https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Linux/shell/commands/uname

Comment: When I run `uname -a` on the unit I get `Linux va-linux 2.6.35.3 #1 PREEMPT Wed Jan 13 15:34:15 EET 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux` 
In this case what is my target?

Comment: `man uname` and read the descriptions of the various flags available. (I'm not sure myself). Good luck.